# run launchclient with parent_last classloader mode in websphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, client, websphere, classloader

I am using launch client in Websphere application `server 8.5.5` to start a standalone java program. It is working fine with default `classLoaderMode` (PARENT_FIRST).

However, when I change it to PARENT_LAST and it failed to initialize application component. Here is command

```
>         File to launch          = C:\workspace\myapp.ear
>         CC Property File        = null
>         Client Jar File         = <default>
>         Alternate DD            = null
>         BootstrapHost           = localhost
>         BootstrapPort           = 2809
>         Trace enabled           = false
>         Tracefile               = null
>         Init only               = false
>         Classpath Parameter     = myjar.jar
>         Security Manager        = disable
>         Security Manager Class  = Not used. -CCsecurityManager=disable
>         Security Manager Policy = Not used. -CCsecurityManager=disable
>         Exit VM                 = true
>         Soap Connector Port     = null
>         Application Parameters  = --name abc
>         Provider URL            = null
>         Dump Java Name Space    = long
>         Admin Connector Host    = null
>         Admin Connector Port    = null
>         Admin Connector Type    = null
>         Admin Connector User    = null
>         PARENT_LAST mode        = true
```

Here is exception:

> WSCL0910I: Initializing component:
>   com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSClientRegistration WSCL0911I: Component initialized
>   successfully. [10/28/17 19:41:10:901 EDT] 00000001  W UOW=
>   source=com.ibm.websphere.naming.genericURLInitialContextFactory
>   thread=[P=69444:O=0:CT]
>             NMSV0907E: Could not invoke method "getObjectInstance" on object of type "com.ibm.ws.naming.urlns.genericURLContextFactory".
>   [10/28/17 19:41:11:145 EDT] 00000001  W UOW=null
>   source=com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers org=IBM prod=WebSphere
>   component=Application Server thread=[P=69444:O=0:CT]
>             NMSV0303E: Exception occurred in NamingManager.getURLContext for the scheme: "services". [10/28/17 19:41:11:169 EDT] 00000001  E
>   UOW=null source=com.ibm.ws.activity.ActivityServiceClientComponentImpl
>   org=IBM prod=WebSphere component=Application Server
>   thread=[P=69444:O=0:CT]
>             WACT0001E: The method start in class com.ibm.ws.activity.ActivityServiceClientComponentImpl received an
>   unexpected exception; the exception stack trace follows:
>   javax.naming.ConfigurationException: Could not invoke method
>   getObjectInstance on object of type com.ibm.ws.naming.ur
>   lns.genericURLContextFactory. [Root exception is
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
>       at com.ibm.websphere.naming.genericURLInitialContextFactory.getAndInvokeMethod(genericURLInitialContextFactory.java:483)
>       at com.ibm.websphere.naming.genericURLContextFactory.getObjectInstance(genericURLContextFactory.java:162)
>       at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getURLContext(NamingManager.java:706)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.getContextIfUrlName(CommonHelpers.java:477)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.CommonHelpers.getContextIfUrlName(CommonHelpers.java:438)
>       at com.ibm.websphere.naming.JndiHelper.recursiveBind(JndiHelper.java:503)
>       at com.ibm.websphere.naming.JndiHelper.recursiveRebind(JndiHelper.java:391)
>       at com.ibm.ws.activity.ActivityServiceClientComponentImpl.start(ActivityServiceClientComponentImpl.java:106)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
>       at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
>       at com.ibm.ws.client.applicationclient.ClientComponentInitImpl.start(ClientComponentInitImpl.java:77)
>       at com.ibm.ws.client.applicationclient.ClientContainer.startComponents(ClientContainer.java:1945)
>       at com.ibm.ws.client.applicationclient.ClientContainer.init(ClientContainer.java:326)
>       at com.ibm.ws.client.applicationclient.launchClient.createContainerAndLaunchApp(launchClient.java:749)
>       at com.ibm.ws.client.applicationclient.launchClient.main(launchClient.java:495)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>       at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
>       at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
>       at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
>       at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>   com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError:
>   javax.naming.ConfigurationException: Could not invoke method
>   getObjectInstance on object of type
>   com.ibm.ws.naming.urlns.genericURLContextFactory. [Root exception is
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>       at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
>       at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
>       at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
>       at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:406)
>       at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:169)
>       at com.ibm.websphere.client.applicationclient.launchClient.main(launchClient.java:246)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
>       at com.ibm.websphere.naming.genericURLInitialContextFactory.getAndInvokeMethod(genericURLInitialContextFactory.java:469)
>       ... 41 more Caused by: javax.naming.ConfigurationException: There is no name space for the URL scheme "services".
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlns.genericURLContextFactory.isNameSpaceAccessable(genericURLContextFactory.java:99)
>       at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextFactory.getObjectInstance(UrlContextFactory.java:85)
>       ... 46 more

What does it cause IBM launch client to load and failed with PARENT_LAST class loader mode? I am wondering if it is an Websphere Application `Server 8.5.5`. Or I just run it incorrectly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can resolve this issue by myself. The problem is I accidentally include the websphere library in classpath. It causes websphere use classpath to initialize my client application and failed to look up jndi. In order to run the launchclient with PARENT_LAST mode, I have to remove websphere jar files in classpath. The process starts and initialize correctly without any issues.

Just post the approach I have here in case anyone have the same issue.